# create correct header and stream info for mjpeg stream

Tags: c, stream, udp, vlc

I'm struggling with trying to create a stream that will be played by VLC. I've checked my stream info and every frame is a valid jpeg image.

For the stream I do (in C):

```
loop:

    // jpg contains 150-200k image
    // sPtr is content length
    ...

    char boundary[100];
    char sPtr[11];
    sprintf(sPtr, "%i", ptr);
    strcpy(boundary,"--myboundary\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: ");
    strcat(boundary, sPtr);
    strcat(boundary, "\r\n\r\n");
    fwrite(&boundary, 1, strlen(boundary), stdout);             
    fwrite(&jpg, 1, ptr, stdout);
    sprintf(boundary, "%s", "\r\n");
    fwrite(&boundary, 1, 2, stdout);
goto loop:
```

What I get is the first few lines of the image and then all green and flickering. I've double, triple checked the images with jpeginfo and jpegsnoop for errors after writing them to a file instead of stdout and there are no errors in the images. Each image size is approximately 150-200k.

I start the c program with ./test | vlc -

Comment: If the images are ok something must be wrong with the header. Please add link to header specification.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding a link to header specification. The only data being sent to vlc is through stdout and those 3 fwrites; boundary, data and \r\n. Is there something else?

Comment: I meant the VLC spec. Can't see how jpg is defined. What is written to stdout ?

Comment: Just what is shown. jpg is just an array containing a full jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Boundary is already a pointer, the & operator is wrong.

```
fwrite(boundary, 1, strlen(boundary), stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I remove the & but still the same problem with the stream.